# How to retrieve build information after build completes in FDT?

Tags: eclipse, flash, apache-flex, build-process, fdt

Using FDT, when I have a debug configuration with several operations in the launcher chain and the final launcher opens in Flash Player, how can I retrieve the build output from the console once the build is complete and Flash player is running?

It seems that once Flash Player has started the console clears to make way for the application's trace output, but I need to be able to look back over the events and build times for each item in my launch chain while Flash Player is running.  Is there a setting I can enable to either log my build output to a file or to preserve it in the console?

**Edit:** I know I can still read the info when building normally, this question is specifically for building with the debugger.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The debugger creates a new console. The build console is still existant. Click the monitor icon in the console view of FDT icon bar and select a previous console.